# by hover have a lot of re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, render, rerender

i have have 2 components, RingSection should render TechnologyItem, by hover i have so much re-renders of component TechnologyItem, and my app work slowly, tries different memo, but nor work ok. how fix that? attached code below.

RingSection.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { activeQuadrantSelector } from "../../../store/selectors/quadrantSelectors";
import TechnologyItem from "../TechnologyItem/TechnologyItem";
import "./ringSection.scss";

const RingSection = ({ currentRing, currentRadarData }) => {
  const activeQuadrant = useSelector(activeQuadrantSelector);
  const technologies = currentRadarData.data.filter(
    ({ ring, quadrant }) =>
      ring === currentRing &&
      quadrant === currentRadarData.quadrants[activeQuadrant]
  );

  if (technologies.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className="ring-name">{currentRing}</h3>
      <div className="tech-items">
        {technologies.map(
          ({ index, name, technologyDescription, contacts, blipTag }) => (
            <TechnologyItem
              index={index}
              name={name}
              key={`${index}-${name}`}
              description={technologyDescription}
              contacts={contacts}
              tags={blipTag}
            />
          )
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


export default RingSection;

TechnologyItem.jsx

import React, { useCallback } from "react";

import { hoveredTechnologySelector } from "../../../store/selectors/quadrantSelectors";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setHoveredTechnologyAction } from "../../../store/actions/quadrantActions";
import "./technologyItem.scss";

const TechnologyItem = ({ index, name, description, contacts, tags }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const hoveredTechnology = useSelector(hoveredTechnologySelector);

  const isHovered = name === hoveredTechnology;

  const onMouseOver = () => {
    dispatch(setHoveredTechnologyAction(name));
  };

  const onMouseOut = () => {
    dispatch(setHoveredTechnologyAction(""));
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={isHovered ? "tech-item-highlighted" : "tech-item"}
      onMouseOver={onMouseOver}
      onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
    >
      <p>
        {index}. {name}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default React.memo(TechnologyItem);
```

i tried React.memo() for component TechnologyItem and useCallback for func `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut`, how fix a lot os re-renders

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are using mouseOver, and mouseOver triggers when you are activing moving the mouse on the stated element, just use **mouseEnter/mouseLeave** instead and it will solve your problem about too much re-render.